# Node.js form submit gives undefined variables

Tags: node.js, express

So I am trying to submit a form via POST to an Express route, but when I use `req.query.` it gives me 'undefined' instead of the form values.

Here is my code:
**app.js:**

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    vhost = require('vhost'),
    http = require('http');

var blob = require('./model/blobs');

var routes = require('./routes/index'),
    blobs = require('./routes/blobs'),
    users = require('./routes/users'),
    marathon = require('./routes/marathon');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(vhost('www.lsaciasi.lo', routes));
app.use(vhost('lsaciasi.lo', routes));
app.use(vhost('recrutari.lsaciasi.lo', blobs));
app.use(vhost('intern.lsaciasi.lo', users));
app.use(vhost('itmarathon.lsaciasi.lo', marathon));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});

if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
        });
    });
}

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

**blobs.js:**

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('blobs', { title: 'LSAC Iasi | Join Us!' });
});

router.post('/sendaction', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
   response = {
       first_name:req.body.nume,
       last_name:req.body.prenume
   };
   console.log(response);
   res.send(response);
});

module.exports = router;
```

..aand part of my index.jade

```
.container-fluid#aplic
  .row
    form(action="/sendaction" method="post" id="form1")
    h2 Aplică
      br
      .textbarr
        h4 Nume:
        input(type="text" name="nume" placeholder="Popescu")
      br
      .textbarr
        h4 Prenume:
        input(type="text" name="prenume" placeholder="Ion")
      br
      .textbarr
        h4 Email:
        input(type="text" name="email" placeholder="popescu.ion@email.com")
      br
      .textbarr
        h4 Telefon:
        input(type="text" name="telefon" placeholder="0743 352 156")
      br
      .textbarr
        h4 Care este viziunea ta desre voluntariat?
        textarea(type="textarea" name="opinie" placeholder="Cum vezi tu sa (te) ajute actiunile de voluntariat?")
      br
      .textbarr
        h4 De ce LSAC?
        textarea(type="textarea" name="motivatie" placeholder="Ce te motiveaza sa aplici aici?")
      br
    .textbarr
      button.btn.btn-success(type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit") Trimite
    br
```

And all I get is: `{ first_name: undefined, last_name: undefined }`.

**EDIT**

my bad, for `first_name:req.query.nume` it woldn't work, but changed with  `first_name:req.body.nume` Same problem, it returns 'undifined'

Comment: req.query is used to pass values in the URL, for example https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl#q=req+query+express.js. Everything after the "?" is an variable inside req.query

Comment: To get the form values, you must use req.body.your_variable

Comment: ok, my bad, for `first_name:req.query.nume` it woldn't work, but `last_name:req.body.nume` should be fine. In my case it returns 'undifined'

Comment: Take a look in my answer ;).

Comment: For the "nume" field, set the id atribute in the field and submit the form again.

Comment: No effect. anyway, the 'name' attribute should be enough...

Comment: uhmm... try it: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`

Comment: You must make sure that you define all configurations **before** defining routes. Define the body-parser (and everything else) before the routes.

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` is used in app.js as well. I can remove theese line from blobs.js (and I did that), in theory it should work but it doesn't :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the error was in the jade doccument.

```
....
.row
  form(action="/sendaction" method="post" id="form1")
  h2 Aplică
    br
    .textbarr
      h4 Nume:
      input(type="text" name="nume" placeholder="Popescu")
....
```

Because of `h2` placed right under `form` it closes the form tag so my form was acctualy empty.

```
 h2 Aplică
 form(action="/sendaction" method="post" id="form1")
```

Now all inputs are in the form and the data is sumbitted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[req.query](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query) is used to pass values in the URL, for example:

```
// URL http://localhost:3000/test/my-id-is-here/edit
router.post('/test/:id/edit', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.id);
    res.send(200);
}
```

In your case, set the `id` HTML attribute in each field inside the form, submit and get the field values using, for example `req.body.email`, `req.body.nume` and so on.